# portal_catalog query for Events over days

Tags: plone

Is it possible to query the portal_catalog for future events AND for current running events?

For example:

```
start >= now <= end or
start <= now <= end
```

Or is there another possible query?

Plone 4
plone.app.event

Comment: I may need more coffee, but isn't that semantically the same as `now <= end`?

Comment: I suffered from not enough coffee. :+1: for the one who really read the question :-D haha this should be the accepted answer for this question ^^

Answer (score 2):

The plone catalog has very limited query options, afaik the only index which supports an `or` operator is the `KeywordIndex`

One possible solution is to split it up in two queries.

```
from DateTime import DateTime

query_current = {}
query_current['start'] = {'query': DateTime(),
                          'range': 'min'}
query_current['end'] = {'query': DateTime(),
                        'range': 'max'}

query_future = {}
query_future['start'] = {'query': DateTime(),
                         'range': 'min'}
query_future['end'] = {'query': DateTime(),
                       'range': 'min'}


items = list(portal_catalog(**query_current)) + list(portal_catalog(**query_future))
```

This is pretty well documented: http://docs.plone.org/4/en/develop/plone/searching_and_indexing/query.html#querying-by-date

The other possibility is called `Products.AdvancedQuery`, but to be honest I never used it, since I guess it's somehow dead --> http://www.dieter.handshake.de/pyprojects/zope/AdvancedQuery.html
You probably can't install it.

Comment: AdvancedQuery works very well on Plone 4.3, so you can install it.
However we experienced a big perfomance problem with it in a huge site when performing date searches.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, i'll try it in a few days

For now this works for me

```
now = localized_now(self.context)
now_timestamp = time.mktime(now.timetuple())

# get all events out of catalog
allEvents = portal_catalog(
    portal_type="Event",
    review_state="published",
    sort_on='start',
    path={'query': nav_root_path}
)
items = []
for i in allEvents:
    start_timestamp = time.mktime(i.start.timetuple())
    end_timestamp = time.mktime(i.end.timetuple())
    if start_timestamp >= now_timestamp <= end_timestamp or\
       start_timestamp <= now_timestamp <= end_timestamp:
        items.append((i, i.start))
```

Comment: Beware: you are waking up all of the objects and not using catalog brains. This can be a performance bottleneck.

Comment: I know, but - Thanks plone4, its fast. Object and Brain gives different results (2016-09-29 13:00:00+02:00 | 2016/09/29 13:00:00 Europe/Vienna) and it was simplier to use Object.start as to convert it